# node/add/[content-type] redirects to front-page

Tags: nodes, redirection, path-aliases

I have 6 content types set up on my site: Article, Artefact, Basic Page, Link, Persona, Quote. All the rest work, but the link to add Quote just redirects to front-page, and I can think of nothing that can cause this behaviour.

node/add/quote -> [front-page]

I've tried clearing cache, running cron, deleting and regenerating paths/clean URLs site-wide. I've also tried all sorts of ways to access the URL including typing by hand into the address bar, but all have led to front-page.

I'd be super-grateful if this can be resolved.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have / haven't had any redirecting modules enabled? Redirect, Global redirect, I18n redirect...

Comment: Did you make sure the user has sufficient permissions to create nodes of type quote?

Comment: May be you have setuped front page url as node/add/quote in site Information.